# drop duplicates according to two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, apply

I am trying to drop duplicate values at column P but according to column S values. I meant that every group in S columns. Like according to S group there are four groups 1,2,3 and 4. and so according to first group i am trying to find values 5,7,6 and 1st index should drop.

```
    S  A4  P
0   1   1  5
1   1   2  5
2   1   3  7
3   1   4  6
4   2   1  7
5   2   2  6
6   2   3  7
7   2   1  1
8   3   5  2
9   3   3  3
10  3   2  4
11  3   1  1
12  4   5  2
13  4   3  3
14  4   5  4
15  4   6  5
```

So every duplicated values at P column according to S group not wanted. This is the searching df that i am trying to find:

```
Search
    S  A4  P
0   1   1  5
1   1   3  7
2   1   4  6
3   2   1  7
4   2   2  6
5   2   1  1
6   3   5  2
7   3   3  3
8   3   2  4
9   3   1  1
10  4   5  2
11  4   3  3
12  4   5  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates()` with `subset` and `keep='first'`:

```
In [2335]: df.drop_duplicates(sub['S', 'P'], keep='first')
Out[2335]: 
    S  A4  P
0   1   1  5
2   1   3  7
3   1   4  6
4   2   1  7
5   2   2  6
7   2   1  1
8   3   5  2
9   3   3  3
10  3   2  4
11  3   1  1
12  4   5  2
13  4   3  3
14  4   5  4
15  4   6  5
```

Comment: But i don't want to drop if a row at P is same with another element but in other group for example third group element.I mean that if i use drop_duplicates and subset for example  i'll lose also 15th row last element of P but i dont want to lose it.

Comment: Did you get what i mean?

Comment: In my example `15th` row is not lost.

Comment: Sorry my fault :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a bit new on programming and Python so thanks for help. I am grateful to you.